# Inheritance and Aggregate Roots

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, aggregateroot

In domain-driven design, we are encouraged to build rich entities which express real concepts in the domain.

Let's say we have an entity `Vehicle` which references an aggregate root, `Person`, by identity - a `Vehicle` is owned by a `Person`.

But, a `Vehicle` can exist at a point of time without an owner, say just after it is manufactured.

**How would you model this?**

One way could be with a `Nullable` type:

```
public class Vehicle : DomainEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid? Owner { get; private set; }

    public Vehicle(...)
        : base(Guid.NewGuid())
    {
        //...
    }

    public Vehicle(Guid owner, ...)
        : base(Guid.NewGuid())
    {
        Owner = owner;
        //...
    }
}
```

Another way is to use multiple classes and inheritance:

```
public class Vehicle : DomainEntity<Guid>
{
    public Vehicle(...)
        : base(Guid.NewGuid())
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class OwnedVehicle : Vehicle 
{
    public Guid Owner { get; private set; }

    public OwnedVehicle(Guid owner, ...)
        : base(Guid.NewGuid())
    {
        Owner = owner;
        //...
    }
}
```

I would much prefer to use the second approach, but can one really model aggregate roots like this?

What exactly would the aggregate root be; `Vehicle` or `OwnedVehicle`?

Would we now have two separate repositories or would the repository return the base type, `Vehicle`?  This would mean that we would need to cast - not ideal.

Comment: If a `Vehicle` is owned by a `Person` wouldn't it be the `Person` who'd have zero or many references to the `Vehicles` they own?  The example you've given is constrained by the constraints imposed by using a relational database.  I.e. it's being constrained by technicalities of a persistence concern.

Comment: sounds like you are dealing with multiple bounded context: Manufacturing and Sales for example

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, a loose definition of an AggregateRoot is not being a subentity, and a subentity is something that can only be understood in reference to another parent entity.  For example, a OrderLine only makes sense in terms of an Order.

A Person and a Car are not this - you can have a Person without a Car, and a Car without a Person in your example.

For cases like this, you have a Service that manages relationships between Aggregate Roots.

https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design/

> The operation relates to a domain concept that is not a natural part of an Entity or Value Object
>
> The interface is defined in terms of other elements in the domain model
>
> The operation is stateless

So in this case, you might have a CarOwnersipService, that can update Cars and People to make ownership happen, but who's details are not known to the outside world.  A service makes sense here because depending on the application the rules may be different.  For example, perhaps you can view who owns a car on a mobile device, but only assign ownership in another application?

What gives me pause here is the operation being stateless - if we consider an idempotent service to be stateless, it does satisfy the definition, but otherwise it does not.